# Can stun damage kill you in Runescape?

Tags: runescape

When thieving guards, people or farmers you sometimes fail and are stunned. When you are stunned damage is dealt to you based on the risk of the thieve. Is it possible to die from these stuns or does your health just drop to an extremely low point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stun damage can and will kill you if you continue to do it.  Many times pickpocketing the Master Farmer I have died.  If I get a chance I will go do it and get a snapshot to further prove this.
[image: stunDamage]

EDIT: Here is the snapshot I promised.  As you can see I was pickpocketing the Master Farmer and I am in the middle of the death animation.