# Will a broodoo victim's snare kill you?

Tags: runescape

In RuneScape doing the Karamja mini-game will sometimes yield a broodoo victim. When the victim snares you, you take 20 damage. Can the snare kill you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can stun damage kill you in Runescape?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142036/can-stun-damage-kill-you-in-runescape)

Comment: @Haidro Stuns are different than snares.

Comment: The mechanics of damage from snares are the same as stun damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes snare damage can kill you.  This is similar to the question asking about if stun damage can kill you but it is the same for the snare from Broodoo Victims.

Comment: I'm not saying this is a bad answer, it just seems incomplete. Could you show some evidence or a source for your information.

Comment: @user61635 It isn't really stated anywhere that I can find I am just going off from my experience of playing.  I will try to get a screenshot, probably won't be from snare though since that would take FAR too long with my Constitution level.  But I will do it for the pickpocket one if I get time and all damage like that is the same.  Anything in Runescape that can outdamage your regen rate can kill you. Poison, scarab swarm(Pyramid Plunder), etc.

Comment: @user61635  I added the snapshot to another question of yours: [Can stun damage kill you in runescape?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142036/can-stun-damage-kill-you-in-runescape)   The mechanics are the same for the snare damage of the Broodoo Victims.